# How do I enable TLSv1.1+ on Xamarin Android (API 16 - 19)?

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to enable `TLSv1.1` or `TLSv1.2` for my Android app (which is built using Xamarin). Android `API 16+` supports both 1.1 & 1.2, but are not enabled by default until `API 20` ([source](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html)). Can anyone explain how to enable `TLSv1.1` or `TLSv1.2`, and use it with .Net's HttpClient (or recommend an alternative to HttpClient).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install [Google Play Services - Safety Net](https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplayservices-safetynet)
and call

```
if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt <= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
{
    ProviderInstaller.InstallIfNeededAsync(ApplicationContext, this);
}
```

`InstallIfNeeded` will enable `tls1.1+` usage. It is required once per application start.
Next - you need to use native HttpMessageHandler for HttpClient, see [ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/modernhttpclient)

Comment: Your solution works perfectly! Thank you so much. Do you have any recommendations to force a webview to use ModernHttpClient?

Comment: @twolf Where do you call this?

Comment: @Kush I call it once in the constructor for a class that inherits from Application (android.app.Application).

Comment: Thank you @twolf I will give this a go :)

Comment: @user1967092 I have exact same requirement but i am not using Xamarin. Is their any solution using normal native Android code?